# Huge memory consumption with Strings

Tags: swift, string, memory, optimization

I'm collecting string data in a struct. In the end I'm writing that string to a file. The results are 4 files each 80 MB. But internaly it occupied nearly 16 GB (!) of RAM forces the OS to swap. (I'm using Swift 3.0)

```
struct ActionCMD {  // struct!
    var cmd = String()

...

    mutating func lines(_ text: String, toTheTop: Bool = false) {
        if toTheTop { cmd  = text + cmd }
        else        { cmd += text }
    }
...
}
```

Any idea why this happens and how to avoid?

Comment: Look like you have a memory leak somewhere. Did you fire up Instruments and check what's using all the memory?

Comment: No, I don't know the tool. I'm searching for it (and how to use) and try to examine that issue.

Comment: Of course it's way around but you can rewrite your `ActionCMD` as `class` if it doesn't hurt to your architecture.

Answer (score 1):

It probably has to do with the method(s) marked as `mutating`. A `mutating` method in Swift will apply its' changes to a new copy of, in this case, the `ActionCMD` instance. Depending on the rest of your code, you might be keeping all those instances around.

Comment: That's interesting. I'm changing the string within the struct, so it's mutating. Is there another way to do this without this effect, but (!) keep it Swift-like? Is switching from struct to class making this even worse? Maybe not, because I don't create more objects instead of changing themselves?

Comment: Structs in Swift are a value type, which doesn't seem to support your use case very well. You could make `ActionCMD` a class with instance variable `var cmdComponents: [String] = []`. When you have filled that array with all strings in the right order, you can make a single string out of it with `cmdComponents.reduce("", combine: +)`.

Comment: Thanks. I did a class and used the array, and it seems that it reduces memory consumption to a half. Still 8,5 GB!? But I don't see any further optimizations.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it is quite difficult to tell you what is going wrong in your app without knowing how you are allocating and deallocating these instances. The problems you are seeing can be related to retain cycles or the way you are collecting your String data. String is a value type and because of that every time you change it a new copy will be produced due to the copy-on-write feature. That said, the best advice I can give you is for you to check this quite [good article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/mo-ios-memory/) on several tips to improve memory management using ObjC and Swift. Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

In C# and Java you would use a stringbuilder, because a new string is created every time you add something if you dont. A stringbuilder allocates the memory only once.

This: http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/StringBuilder/ seems to be a port from Java to Swift, haven't tested it, but you could give it a try.

This one: https://gist.github.com/kristopherjohnson/1fc55e811d944a430289 is very bad (first result on google sadly). It is not a stringbuilder, just a wrapper around the normal methods.